# Grouping various tags regarding energy efficiency

Tags: discussion, status-completed, retag-request, tags

I've recently gained the rep to retag, so when I saw [this](https://superuser.com/questions/171362/multicore-cpu-energy-requirement-and-load-balancing) question and didn't think the `energy` tag made sense (yes it's about *energy*, but really something like "energy efficiency" would be more relevant) I decided to change it, so went to search for the current "standard" tag for that type of question and found there is instead a mess of similar tags.

Since I've only recently gained the rep to retag I thought I'd defer this to the community, rather than go on an unguided retagging spree.

I think the following tags are all used for the same purpose:

- energy (6 questions)
- energy-saver (2)
- power-consumption (13)
- power-efficiency (2)
- powersave (4)

There is also an `efficiency` tag with 6, but those questions seem to be more about personal / time efficenty - not electrical energy.

Then, there is the `electricity` tag with 45, which I think is being used for the same purposes *some of the time*, but for some other purposes as well - [brownouts](https://superuser.com/questions/131490/few-questions-on-clone-zilla), [electrocution](https://superuser.com/questions/127387/what-will-happen-if-i-accidentally-pour-a-bucket-of-water-inside-my-pc) and [preventing damage](https://superuser.com/questions/133864/whats-the-best-way-to-spray-paint-the-inside-of-my-case) for example.

I think those I've bulletted need to be merged and/or have synonyms (I guess the primary tag should be `power-consumption`?), and then adjust those in `electricity` that match? Does that make sense?

#### Edit

Since no one's responsed, I shall go and re-tag these once I'm home this evening, unless someone decides to say otherwise before then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Done.

Result was to keep 20 as `power-consumption`, and also 7 as `powersave` (for those RE the power *settings* on machines, maybe could do with a better name...) with some shuffling between the lot.